# Get only items with a pattern from sharedpreference

Tags: android

I have values in sharedpreference in my app. I have items like

```
itemH1
item1
itemH2
item2
itemH3
item3
```

How can i get only the items like `itemHX`?

Comment: Is that just one value? Separated with spaces?

Comment: I want to get all the items with the key pattern itemH

Comment: And do you know how much items with key itemH there is? If so perform a for. Otherwise you have to get all the settings and compare one by one

Comment: No i don't know previously how many items I have in sharedpreference with this pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are all stored in a single preferences file, then you are pretty much limited to using [`SharedPreferences.getAll()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getAll()) and iterating through the map entries to find keys matching your pattern.

The other option is to make a different preferences file (using [`Context.getSharedPreferences(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String,%20int)) for the special items (in your example, the ones with the H). This way you can just read all the keys in that file and not have to check for a pattern.

Comment: it's a solution but what can i do if I need to use both sharedpreference files in a adapter for display values in a listview (also using AsyncTask for display images in the listview)?

Comment: You would probably get better advice if we had some idea what kind of data you are storing and how you plan to use it. I'm not sure I like the idea of using SharedPreferences to back a ListView adapter. I would prefer something that allows encapsulating the data for each item, whereas here you are using  two or more shared preferences that are not linked in any way except for some similarity between the names of the keys.

Answer (score 2):

You have to iterate all the sharepreference items and compare one by one if it matches your pattern.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = ctx.getSharedPreferences(AppSettings.PREFERENCES_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Map<String, ?> allEntries = sharedPref.getAll();
        for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : allEntries.entrySet()) {
            if(entry.getKey().contains("itemH"))  //you can use startsWith too
                Log.d("itemH found", entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue().toString());
        }
```